# Pass URL values to SecondView Controller WebView (WKWebView)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, wkwebview

I have implemented QR Scanner code, upon scanning I am already getting URL string, which I need to pass it secondview controller to WKWebView. But whenever I try to pass URL string it becomes `null` or open in separate view. As its not opening properly in secondview controller. 
İssue: need to pass url value to second controller webview. 
First View Controller:
Contains QR scanning code -- getting URL.
Second View Controller: 
Contains WebView to display URL data.

First Controller Code:

```
if let url = URL(string: decodedURL) {
    let vc = SecondViewController(nibName: "SecondViewController", bundle: nil)
    let url = URL(string: decodedURL)
    vc.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height))
    vc.webView.autoresizingMask = UIView.AutoresizingMask(rawValue: UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleWidth.rawValue | UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleHeight.rawValue)
    vc.webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
    self.view.addSubview(vc.webView)
    vc.webView.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Second ViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Comment: Are you getting null or url is not loading in webview? Can you please confirm?

Comment: In your example you are not really "passing a URL", you are assigning it to the destination viewController webView. Does it display an error? By the way the second `let url = URL(string: decodedURL)` should be deleted, and the `self.view.addSubview(vc.webView)` seems suspicious in your example

Comment: @Khushbu not loading appropriate in secondviewcontroller. WebView is part of second controller, if I only pass url value from first to second controller İ think WebView will work properly.

Comment: @Olympiloutre yes you are right. İ need to modify that İ will pass only URL to secondcontroller so İ can pass this value to WebView to show data. but if i removed self.view.addSubview(vc.webView) it won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Add following variable in `SecondViewController`:

```
var url: URL?
```

In `viewDidLoad` method of `SecondViewController` add following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let url = self.url {
        self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
}
```

Inside `FirstController`, update code as follows:

```
if let url = URL(string: decodedURL) {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    vc.url = url
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

I hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you exactly the same, but problem is now after modified the code its not navigating to second controller.

Comment: `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)` . not working, even not navigating to second controller.

Comment: I have created test project and still navigation is not working. `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)` Sample test project link attached. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WUTq2BhFNRBHFJMtpTUSY56tDTuJZWfx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Make sure `navigationController` not nil

Comment: In `Main.storyboard`, Select `ViewController` then from menu bar, select `Editor` -> `Embed In` -> `Navigation Controller`

Comment: Accept answer. So that's useful to other people also.